# Why WordPress cache is not available after reload page?

Tags: cache

I try to put data into WordPress cache and get it after reload page.
I test my code and find out that data added to cache currently but after I reload page this cache is empty and `wp_cache_get` method return false.

How can i fix this?

```
<?php

    $cache_name = 'products';

    $wp_cache_get_products = wp_cache_get($cache_name);
    var_dump($wp_cache_get_products);


    if ($wp_cache_get_products == false) {

        $args = [
            'post_type'   => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'nopaging'    => true
        ];
        $product_list = new WP_Query($args);
        $posts = $product_list->get_posts();

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $output[] = [
                'id'    => $post->ID,
                'value' => $post->post_title,
                'url'   => get_permalink($post->ID),
                'image' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID)
            ];


        }
        var_dump($output);
        wp_cache_set($cache_name, $output);
    }
    //echo json_encode($output);
    var_dump(wp_cache_get($cache_name));

?>
```

Comment: It's not supposed to. The WordPress cache is not persistent. It's for caching things for re-use during a single page load.

Comment: But cache must available until cache expired or cleared

Comment: See [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache): "By default, the object cache is non-persistent. This means that data stored in the cache resides in memory only and only for the duration of the request. Cached data will not be stored persistently across page loads unless you install a persistent caching plugin."

Comment: OK. This is right that after WordPress 2.5 cache disabled and we can not use it. But I think this is mistake  that do WordPress. Cache data in server memory is big option that WordPress excluded it.

Comment: WordPress 2.5 was 10 years ago. You can read about why it was removed [here](https://neosmart.net/blog/2008/wordpress-25-and-the-object-cache/).